# How do I introduce a new event denormalizer in a CQRS system?

Tags: cqrs

According to [CQRS à la Greg Young](http://cre8ivethought.com/blog/2009/11/12/cqrs--la-greg-young), event handlers (and the downstream event denormalizers) react on incoming events that were published before by the event publisher.

Now lets suppose that at runtime we want to add a new event denormalizer: Basically, this is easy, but it needs to get to its data to the current state.

What is the best way to do this?

Should I send an out-of-order request to the event store and ask for all previously emitted events?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch and replay all (required) events against the new handler. This can be done in a separate process since what you essentially want is to get the persisted view models into the proper state.

Have a look at Rinat Abdullin's [Lokad.CQRS](http://lokad.github.com/lokad-cqrs/) sample project for a production example. Especially the [**`SaaS.Engine.StartupProjectionRebuilder`**](https://github.com/Lokad/lokad-cqrs/blob/master/SaaS.Engine/StartupProjectionRebuilder.cs) might be an interesting source even though it's rather complex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link. I think that it's a good idea to run this as a separate process, it's also basically clear to me how to do it. The only question is: Who kicks this off? The event handler? The administrator "manually"? ...?

Comment: I've seen that basically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559096/cqrs-how-to-handle-new-report-tables-or-how-to-import-all-history-from-the-e?rq=1 answers this question.

Answer (score 4):

One can also build the projections so that they remember what event they saw last. Then on any startup, they ask for this event and all forward. Re-starting an old projection and building a new one then become roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you embrace bounded context complex integration you may need to drop the entire read model and rebuild it.